# .bash_profile on Mac OS X Leopard breaks Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, unix, terminal

I am relatively new to dealing with command line issues, compiling programs, and UNIX. Coming from a PHP background, I just fired off MAMP and never worried about this kind of stuff.

I am diving into Rails, and running into some issues. I tried to create a .bash_profile in my home directory to create some shortcuts for myself. I added `/usr/local/git/bin` to my .profile file, but it seems to have no effect on my PATH variable inside a new terminal window (i.e. it only lasts the session).

The .bash_profile seemed to persist across logins, but once I had that setup, Rails stopped working as expected! I would run `rails server` in my application's root directory, and Rails would create a new app called `'server'` with another directory tree inside my existing app. It does this even with an empty .bash_profile. But I delete the .bash_profile, and everything works like normal.

I am in over my head here - I have very little understanding of how this all works. Any advice on where to look? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: can you paste your profile's $PATH variables?

Comment: What do you get if you open Terminal.app and `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post what you added to your .bash_profile. To pre-pend something to your path the syntax is:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to append you swap the "/usr/local/bin" and $PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

After you make changes to your .bash_profile you can make them available in the current terminal session by running `source .bash_profile`. Then if you run `echo $PATH` you can see the updated PATH. You should try running `rails --version` in your different configurations to see if the version is changing. That may account for your odd behavior.

Comment: I commented out all of the lines in the .bash_profile - it is like it breaks Rails by its mere existence. I imagine it is changing the shell environment somehow, although I can't imagine how since it is effectively an empty document. Then again, I know almost nothing about this!

Comment: A difference in the value of your $PATH variable could make funny things happen. `echo $PATH` will show you the current value. You can also check which executable is being used by running `which` i.e. `which ruby` or `which rails`, it should print the path to the executable that is on your path.

Answer (score 0):

also checkout:
[path-helper](http://littlesquare.com/2008/01/upgraded-to-leopard-making-use-of-etcpathsd-and-path_helper/) as extend PATH is sooo 2010

Comment: Your heading speaks of leopard instead of snow leopard, so you can safely ignore this post I think.